# Parsing a File from Desktop

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I'm using OSX. I have a text file on my desktop and I'm trying to read data from the text file (call it data.txt) and put it into an array. The text file is structured as follows:

```
[
"abc1, abc2, 47872, happy",
"abc3, abc4, 23232, sad",
"abc5, abc6, 64242, tired",
"abc7, abc8, 25542, chilly",
"abc9, abc10, 23244, warm",
]
```

Here is some code I am trying to start with to get this.

```
var request = require('request');

var commaDelimiter = ','; 
var newlineDelimiter = ' '; 

var firstArray =[];
var unsortedOutputArray= [];
var sortedOutputArray = [];


request('/Users/user/Desktop/data.txt', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        body.split(commaDelimiter).forEach(function (item, index) {
            arrayOfStrings.push(item); 
            array.push(parseInt(item));

    console.log(firstArray[0]);
        });
    }
})
```

The issue I'm having is trying to figure out where I am going wrong with this.
I wanted to `console.log` the elements in the array to verify that it was being passed correctly but nothing was being displayed. Can anyone help figure out where I am having issues?
I don't think I need the status code 200 since it's a local file, but can anyone advise. The two things I believe could be problems are

1. how I set up the path for the file on my desktop - i.e. did I do
   this correctly? and
2. did I set up the request correctly in the first place (this I am not so sure about)

Comment: You should use the `fs` module to read files from the file system: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: it's already an array, so just call JSON.parse() on the string

Comment: Request is for HTTP. Local files aren't  HTTP.

Comment: Let me try this out. Thanks for the input so far

Comment: Is the path name correct? i.e. Users/user/Desktop/data.json - is that how I would set it up given that is the location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of calling it data.txt, you can call it data.json (since the file contains a JSON-encoded array of strings, but make sure that rogue last comma gets removed or it won't qualify as legal JSON) and then you can just require it in from its file location:

```
var data = require("/Users/user/Desktop/data.json");
console.log(data[0]) // => abc1, abc2, 47872, happy
```

and then do whatever else is logical, llike

```
var data = require("...");
data.forEach(function(row) {
  var terms = row.split(", ");
  terms.forEach(function(term) {
    console.log(term)
  });
});
```

Comment: Upvoted, but make sure you remove the comma after the last element in the array.

Comment: technically not necessary: this is a legal array with an empty last element (IE will die on that, node.js shouldn't)

Comment: Technically, it dies on my machine :) mostly because it's JSON and not JS.